# Upload file programmatically

Tags: php, javascript, upload, applet, hta

Can I programmatically upload a file to the server (without client's interference) ? I know this is not possible in normal (.html) files. Is there anyway I can do it from .hta file? or any server side or plug-gin solution?

Comment: if you are doing it programmatically, how would you choose the files to be uploaded?

Comment: I don't think you can do this due to security restrictions.

Comment: @macha hardcoding of course @robbrit .hta removes those restrictions I guess.

Comment: what do you mean without client's interference? I suggest you one simple thing do SCP from client machine to server. :p

Comment: how would you know the files and file locations on a user's computer?? can you explain a little more?

Comment: Ya there's no way to know with unknown client. agreed. I am talking about a small app that will get downloaded on already registered clients (file location found from database) PC, upload the log file (or any other file). That will save writing and installing a separate app for client just for uploading a single file.

Comment: Why would you use a webpage for this? Just write an app to do this...

Comment: @drachestern I know that. I am gonna do the same if don't get any solution!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from an HTA, you can use the shell object to run commands just as if you were running from the command line - including FTP - but of course you'll need FTP credentials.  since you said you'll be able to hardcode the files to be uploaded, i assume you have full access...

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject('wscript.shell');
var params = // this should be a string of ftp commands, like OPEN ftp.example.com USER PASS CWD somedir PUT c:\whatever.txt BYE
shell.run("%comspec% /c ftp.exe -i -s:" + params, 1, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

It may be possible on **some** machines using a signed java applet - but from the wording of the question, that's going to be a very long juorney for you.

Comment: Wording? long journey? didn't get your direction.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, you might atleast need the user to load a web page. So based on an onload function, you can use an ajax hidden form to submit whatever files that you'd want to.

But getting information from your user without their knowledge might put you in a legal situation.

Good luck!!

Comment: ajax hidden form to submit whatever files that you'd want to? not possible. Was trying for the same for some time. You are not allowed to change 'value' of 'file' input tag using javascript